# How to iterate over column values for unique rows of a data frame with sorted, numerical index with duplicates in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I have a pandas `DataFrame` with the sorted, numerical index with duplicates, and the column values are identical for the same values of the index in the given column. I would like to iterate through the values of the given column for the unique values of the index.

Example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [3, 3, 5], 'b': [4, 6, 8]}, index=[1, 1, 2])

   a  b
1  3  4
1  3  6
2  5  8
```

I want to iterate through the values in column `a` for the unique entries in the index - `[3,5]`.

When I iterate using the default `index` and print the type for column `a`, I get the Series entries for the duplicate index entries.

```
for i in df.index:
    cell_value = df['a'].loc[i]
    print(type(cell_value))
```

Output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

Comment: A slight change: `for i in df.index.unique():`

Comment: If I use `for i in df.index.unique():` I get the following types 

`<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'numpy.int64'>`

Comment: Is that not what you're expecting? If not, can you show what your expected output is to look like?

Comment: I would like two integer values corresponding to the unique values of the index.

Comment: In this example the cell_value would have values [3,5] during the iteration.

Comment: Ah, now it makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: I have updated the description based on your input, thanks!

Comment: Appreciate that. Wrote an answer.

Comment: @KrzysztofSłowiński - So question is about duplicates in index? Because get 3 answers about it and one not.

Comment: The question is what is the recommended way of iterating in such a situation to only visit duplicates once. Recommended in terms of a clean solution in the code.

Comment: @KrzysztofSłowiński What solution do you feel works best here? I'm wondering if there is a bigger picture to this problem that we're missing.

Comment: For me the most important is the question of performance and readability, that's why I asked about the recommendations. The big picture is the ability to read the code some time after writing it and see that there is an iteration over unique values happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove duplicated index by mask and assign positions by `arange`, then select with `iloc`:

```
arr = np.arange(len(df.index))
a = arr[~df.index.duplicated()]
print (a)
[0 2]

for i in a:
    cell_value = df['a'].iloc[i]
    print(type(cell_value))

<class 'numpy.int64'>
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

No loop solution - use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) and inverted mask by `~`:

```
a = df.loc[~df.index.duplicated(), 'a']
print (a)
1    3
2    5
Name: a, dtype: int64

b = df.loc[~df.index.duplicated(), 'a'].tolist()
print (b)
[3, 5]

print (~df.index.duplicated())
[ True False  True]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `np.unique`:

```
_, i = np.unique(df.index, return_index=True)
df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc('a')].tolist() 

[3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems an [XY Problem](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwimteqf3dfZAhXqCMAKHbC2BncQFjAAegQIABAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F66377%2Fwhat-is-the-xy-problem&usg=AOvVaw1RW8UpIl7QYxoW-PU7zAk9) if, as per your comment, same index means same data.

You also don't need a loop for this.

Assuming you want to remove duplicate rows and extract the first column only (i.e. 3, 5), the below should suffice.

```
res = df.drop_duplicates().loc[:, 'a']

# 1    3
# 2    5
# Name: a, dtype: int64
```

To return types:

```
types = list(map(type, res))

print(types)
# [<class 'numpy.int64'>, <class 'numpy.int64'>]
```

Comment: The `res` data frame is the original one but without the duplicates in it, and the original `df` remains unchanged, yes?

Comment: See update. this drops duplicates by index. But you should really think about what you are trying to achieve. if row data is different for same index, do you want to keep first, or last?

Comment: I have updated the description - we can assume that for the same values of the index the data will be identical in the columns that I am iterating over.

Comment: I am not suggesting that the solution should use a loop, I was curious about the best way to solve it.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarifying. My answer would be not to use a loop, as in my example. Hope you find it useful.

Comment: Yes, definitely, it is a valid solution.

Comment: I have modified the problem description, assuming that the `df` contains different values in some columns for the duplicated index entries. It was an assumption that I did not describe properly when I was asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using groupby and apply:

```
df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: type(x.a.iloc[0]))
Out[330]: 
1    <class 'numpy.int64'>
2    <class 'numpy.int64'>
dtype: object
```

To make your loop solution to work, create a temp df:

```
df_new = df.groupby(level=0).first()
for i in df_new.index:
    cell_value = df_new['a'].loc[i]
    print(type(cell_value))

<class 'numpy.int64'>
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

Or to use drop_duplicates()

```
for i in df.drop_duplicates().index:
    cell_value = df.drop_duplicates()['a'].loc[i]
    print(type(cell_value))

<class 'numpy.int64'>
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```